# Why does my phone sometimes reboot when playing music?

Tags: motorola-droid-x, music

My Droid X spontaneously reboots when it's playing music.  I've confirmed this behavior with the native music player, Amazon's MP3 player, and now Spotify (though, with Spotify, it seems to happen less often).

No warning, and no pattern, the phone just goes silent mid-song, then reboots.  Sometimes it does it on consecutive days, sometimes it doesn't do it for a week.

It's perfectly stable at all other times, and has never spontaneously rebooted outside of when I'm playing music.

Comment: You don't seem to be the only one having this trouble. See this thread: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1283773

Comment: I think its general error with android, my phone that does that now and again, usually the more time it has been playing the more likely it will reboot, however not always.

Comment: I finally got a log of my phone doing this. Relevant section: https://gist.github.com/1515675. Anyone know what to make of "W/dalvikvm( 1315): threadid=23: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018560)"?

Answer (score 1):

I think it was a memory issue.  I installed Auto Memory Manager, set it on "mild" and never had the problem again.